# What would you call a person who has a soft spot for someone?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

What would be the term be for a person who has a soft spot for someone. To explain my question : a person who loves is a lover, but what if you respect and have an admiration for a celebrity you don’t know or don’t like romantically but really respect. What would you be called then?

Comment: I would have suggested an "admirer" but that's often associated with a romantic interest.

Comment: exactly!! i cant decipher a term for this either

Comment: You'll have to be more specific about the precise nature and degree of the affection. You may think someone is a good writer/actor/singer, or you may follow their actions obsessively, or copy them, or be inspired by them to do something, or you may actually stalk them. Similarly, there are special terms for fans or followers of different kinds of people and different types of attraction. Otherwise, you're left with very general terms like admirer or liker.

Comment: With "respect and admiration" I think you are using "to have a soft spot for someone" not quite idiomatically.  It means to feel an affection for someone, often to the point of overlooking or dismissing their less than admirable qualities or behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Someone who respects and admires a celebrity is called a

> **fan**
>
> [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fan):
> someone who admires and supports a person, sport, sports team, etc.
>
> [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fan):
> an ardent admirer or enthusiast (as of a celebrity or a pursuit).

The word **fan** can also be applied to non-celebrities, such as a person who is not in your peer group, or a colleague, whose actions you approve.

Comment: fan would be a follower i’m talking about someone who has a soft spot not limited to just a celebrity

Comment: You asked about a crush on a celebrity.

Comment: it was an example, i am sorry plus i didnt ask in terms of a crush or a romantic feeling

Comment: A **fan** can be an admirer of anybody, as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: main concern is soft spot.

Comment: @lav  Here is a thesaurus link to synonyms of "soft spot": https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/soft_spot.html

Comment: @lav I've never heard anyone saying they have a soft spot for a celebrity; it's usually a relative, friend, coworker or even a pupil. It's only when you *know* someone do you develop a special fondness for that individual.

Answer (score 0):

Some dictionaries define “appreciator” as someone who assesses or appraises something of value but [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/appreciator) defines the verb *appreciate* as “to value or admire highly”.

In the right context, the term appreciator, will mean someone who appreciates the work of an artist or the artist themself.

### appreciator

Dan Wilson talking about Rick Rubin:

> *…so we met and he became—I guess what you'd say is that in some areas, like recording—a mentor to me. And in the music area, he definitely became a partner. He's **a huge appreciator of great songs** and he seems to think that I write them.* (2010)

Annie Lennox:

> Yes, well, I'm not looking at people as being "fans". I've always had a bit of slight issue with that word. I mean it's quite good to use it to describe people who like my music or appreciate it in one way as being a "fan" of the music. But I always sort of try to say to people - look, find out your own potentiality. Don't look to other people and put them on a pedestal, it's pointless. Find your own strength. Look to your own strengths and weaknesses and be your own self. I'd rather have a word like an "appreciator" of my music. **An appreciator of who I am or what I do**. (2008)